# How can I access sqlite database on a webserver in codename one

Tags: codenameone

Pls How can I access sqlite database on the webserver in codename one? I can only use database API to access database on the device. In order to access this on the webserver I think is quite different thing. Pls I need a snippet code on this. Thanks

Comment: Does your web server code returns JSON or XML and does the same code accept HTTP POST or GET requests? What language was your server side code written with?

Comment: It returns both JSON and XML also accepted HTTP POST or GET requests. server side language php

Comment: SQLite runs on the device, in the server you need to have a webserver. The database behind the webserver is "hidden" (or encapsulated) by that server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code below, not tested and you may have to adjust it to suite your need. Leave a comment if there's an issue:

```
ConnectionRequest req = new ConnectionRequest() {
    @Override
    protected void handleException(Exception ex) {
        //handle error
    }
};
req.setUrl(YourURL);
req.setPost(true);
req.setHttpMethod("POST"); //Change to GET if necessary
req.setDuplicateSupported(true);
req.addArgument("argumentToSendThroughPostOrGet1", "value1");
req.addArgument("argumentToSendThroughPostOrGet2", "value2");
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(req);

if (req.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    Map<String, Object> out = new HashMap<>();
    Display.getInstance().invokeAndBlock(() -> {
        JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
        try (InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(req.getResponseData()))) {
            out.putAll(p.parseJSON(r));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //handle error
        }
    });
    if (!out.isEmpty()) {
         List<Map<String, Object>> responses = (List<Map<String, Object>>) out.get("response");
         for (Object response : responses) {
             Map res = (Map) response;
             System.out.println(res.get("key"));
         }
    } else {
        //handle error
    }
} else {
    //handle error
}
```

**TEST JSON RESPONSE:**

```
{
    "response": [
        {
            "key": "I was returned",
        }
    ]
}
```

**EDIT:**

To pass data from TextField:

```
req.addArgument("argumentToSendThroughPostOrGet1", myTextField.getText());
```

Based on your comment, you can read those arguments in PHP as simple as below:

```
$var1 = $_POST["argumentToSendThroughPostOrGet1"];
$var1 = $_GET["argumentToSendThroughPostOrGet1"]; // if GET method is used in Codename One
//Or use $_REQUEST which supports both methods but not advisable to be used for production
...
```

And you can use those variables in your php code normally.

**Example of Usage with MySql Query:**

```
class Connection {

    function connect() {
        $mysqli = mysqli_init();
        $mysqli->real_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "databaseName") or die('Could not connect to database!');
        $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
        return $mysqli;
    }

    function close() {
        mysqli_close($this->connect);
    }

}


$connection = new Connection();
$mysqli = $connection->connect();
$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ColumnName LIKE '%$var1%' ORDER BY PrimaryKeyId ASC LIMIT 100");
```

Comment: Thanks for your concern, I am very grateful for this great response. Pls is the code above interact with the sqlite Database file?. Because i want to call record inside the sqlite database. Sorry for this question pls. Thanks

Comment: No, this is for databases that work with Webservices, like OracleDb, MySql, or MsSQL. Only use SqlLite if you require a database that will be bundled with the app and that's a different implementation from this, completely.

Comment: Thanks Diamond Mubaarak, when I tested the code it printed I was returned. which means it works. Now what I want to do is that, I will supply a value using TextField in codename one, this value will be compared with what i have in mysql database, if the value is exist, I will update a column as active. Pls how do i pass this value to php page. Thanks

Comment: Thanks For your Immediate response, you are great. Thanks once again. I will feed you back Sir.

Comment: pls sorry for worrying you Mr. Diamond Mubaarak. if I use this url:   private static final String DESTINATION_URL = "http://localhost/webpin/pin.php"; it will not return any value. if use   private static final String DESTINATION_URL = "http://localhost/webpin/che.json"; it  returns values for me. I dont know what am getting wrong

Comment: I used the code below to return php page to json:     header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('respons'=>$posts));

Comment: Ask this in a separate question and tag it Codename One. This thread is already long and moving away from the initial question.

Comment: Thanks, have asked the question separately.Thanks